# Filtering listbox according to textbox search : WPF

Tags: wpf, listbox, filtering

This question might look like a dupe but i found no solution when i ran through entire posts on stackoverflow regarding this question.

I have a listbox and a textbox. The listbox is binded to a list(a class with a single property of type string) in the code-behind.

I just want to filter the items in listview according to the search typed. Following is my code-behind

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Sellers> sellerList = new List<Sellers>();
        sellerList = DAL_Sellers.LoadSellers();
        sellerListView.DataContext = sellerList;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx). This class wraps your source list and allow you to sort, group and filter it.